# How to deal with unequal element list to unpack into multiple variables (ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4))

Tags: python, list, valueerror

I want to extract data from my dataset, but I found out that the list contain nested list with unequal element length inside.

My code that get unpacked value from list

```
obtainedDatetime, itemName, itemType, itemRarity, bannerCode, obtainedTimestamp = item
```

Dataset that contains 4 elements.

```
[
  "2021-04-20 04:19:22",
  "Skyrider Sword",
  "Weapon",
  3
]
```

Dataset that contains 6 elements (but I want only first 4 elements)

```
[
  "2022-01-10 16:26:53",
  "Bloodtainted Greatsword",
  "Weapon",
  3,
  "301",
  "1641801960000166133"
]
```

If the list contains 6 element, Python will raise an error.

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

When I set the variable to get the unpacked value to 6, I recieved an error.

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 4)
```

How to handle the unequal element in the nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extended iterable unpacking features:

```
obtainedDatetime, itemName, itemType, itemRarity, bannerCode, obtainedTimestamp, *rest = item
```

So, `rest` will contain a list with the rest of the iterable. If you are not interested in this data, conventionally, we would name it `_`. So:

```
obtainedDatetime, itemName, itemType, itemRarity, bannerCode, obtainedTimestamp, *_ = item
```

Comment: I found out that I can slice the list to limit the length then iterate over sliced list, but this implementation is needed in case of unpack from list to multiple variables. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack a container into any number of variables, capturing whatever remains in a dummy variable like this:

```py
a, b, c, *_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a    # 1
b    # 2
c    # 3
_    # [4, 5, 6]
```

The key is the `*` before the last variable (which could be given a name, as well).